# A combination of a specific WordPress plugin + Modsecurity is causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-security

I'm using one of the WooCommerce Appointment plugin and it's causing a 500 internal error.

It seems the Modsecurity intercepts the http access but I don't know what's wrong in the following log.

> --a7316b05-A-- [02/Dec/2020:01:37:02 +0800] X8Z-PAqMAA4AAAp171YAAAAE 210.242.3.205 53878 10.140.0.14 443
>
> --a7316b05-B-- GET /wp-admin/admin.php?post_type=wc_appointment&page=appointment_calendar&calendar_month=12&view=month&tab=calendar&filter_appointable_product=&filter_appointable_staff=&calendar_month=11&calendar_year=2020
> HTTP/1.1 Host: homie.tw Connection: keep-alive
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel
> Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36 Accept:
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
> Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate Sec-Fetch-User:
> ?1 Sec-Fetch-Dest: document Referer:
> https://homie.tw/wp-admin/admin.php?page=appointment_calendar&calendar_year=2020&calendar_month=12&view=month
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language:
> zh-TW,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.5 Cookie:
> wordpress_sec_39c5768458d20eee442b5f013f95c6e4=chihao.weng%40gmail.com%7C1606879569%7CIYBGng45F7DiEjkIlD5y2rCpJPu7QdupcJsax3TNQmT%7C99241b7eeb1b6d93b810479b22b84ecc4ff13e5394d5798b59840f4f759f649d;
> mp_a36067b00a263cce0299cfd960e26ecf_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%221736f1935d51cd-0a84c5198fb224-31617402-fa000-1736f1935d6df1%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%221736f1935d51cd-0a84c5198fb224-31617402-fa000-1736f1935d6df1%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fhomie.tw%2Fwp-admin%2Fplugins.php%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22homie.tw%22%7D;
> _ga=GA1.2.332580245.1599972620; energyplus-u=8d66286c0cdf0413991242985d297257;
> wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check;
> tk_ai=woo%3ADAEy5asYphPD0Q3i1p5KUhdQ;
> woocommerce_recently_viewed=1106%7C1433%7C1104%7C1105%7C1103%7C1101;
> wordpress_logged_in_39c5768458d20eee442b5f013f95c6e4=chihao.weng%40gmail.com%7C1606879569%7CIYBGng45F7DiEjkIlD5y2rCpJPu7QdupcJsax3TNQmT%7C0af3928e6a5cc78caf2d4fc871526abac2817b1604d085a887e9f81a7bc76fe2;
> wp-settings-1=libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dtinymce%26hidetb%3D1;
> wp-settings-time-1=1606706772; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1;
> woocommerce_cart_hash=0737a3efd621083e63e459451c8eb2b8;
> wp_woocommerce_session_39c5768458d20eee442b5f013f95c6e4=1%7C%7C1606879577%7C%7C1606875977%7C%7Cf29b691703754018bf8562fa8f40249c
>
> --a7316b05-F-- HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Referrer-Policy:
> strict-origin-when-cross-origin Content-Length: 2789 Connection: close
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> --a7316b05-H-- Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php Stopwatch: 1606844220929440 1447814 (- - -) Stopwatch2: 1606844220929440 1447814;
> combined=9964, p1=429, p2=8091, p3=65, p4=1265, p5=113, sr=13, sw=1,
> l=0, gc=0 Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked Producer: ModSecurity
> for Apache/2.9.1 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/3.2.0.
> Server: Apache Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"
>
> --a7316b05-Z--

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: I noticed a `strict-origin-when-cross-origin ` error in the log. Did you change wordpress' domain recently? Or did you more from www to non-www version recently? Try saving your permalinks again (in settings menu)

Comment: I tried to change header to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  but it still throw 500 error

I don't see any error in apache/error.log. The 500 error only shown in modsec_audit.log

I made a video how it happened. https://streamable.com/14rzyz